# Print session array data each separately for further use

Tags: php, html, arrays

As in the title i manage to pass the session array to other file and print it using "echo join" and "print_r".
I want to print them separately and use them later. For example  i want to sum the quantity of days * price and show it.
Any ideas about ot or im doing it wrong and have to change more stuff.

here is the code ( from pastebin)

cars.php :( here is my shopping cart based on array)

https://pastebin.com/Q9euzvG7

summarise.php ( here i am passing array using session.)

```
<?php
      $array["shopping_cart"] = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"];
      foreach ($array["shopping_cart"] as $value) {
      print_r($value);
      echo join(',',$value);
      echo  $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]["quantity"];
?>
```

https://pastebin.com/CFhuAt3M

PS. Im sorry about code edit.

Update :

[Table from sql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tTC8.png)

And the Shopping cart array :

```
   if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
{
  if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
 {
     $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
     if(!in_array($_GET["id_samochodu"], $item_array_id))
     {
        $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        $item_array = array(
            'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id_samochodu"],
            'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'item_brand'        =>  $_POST["hidden_brand"],
            'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Już dodałeś ten samochód do koszyka") 
</script>';
    }
  }
 else
 {
     $item_array = array(
        'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id_samochodu"],
        'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'item_brand'        =>  $_POST["hidden_brand"],
        'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]
     );
     $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
 }
```

}

Comment: Further use?.. like what??

Comment: So you echo out values, concatenated by commas. Fine. What is the issue with that?

Comment: Maybe that's a bad idea i want to print it like : "Order details and some stuff from shopping cart. Thinking about multiplying quantity and price and print it also.

Comment: @arkascha besides commas i want to type like:  brand of the car : Value , price of the car : value, quantity of days to rent : value ect. If u know how to do it using join or using some other way ill be glad to see that :).

Comment: So you want to output prompts and corresponding values. Where does the text for the prompts come from? I assume you will have to implement a mapping between prompt text and element key of the values inside that array. We cannot help with that if you do not add how that array of values looks like.

Comment: @arkascha  first pastebin link is the code u looking for  :) here u go : https://pastebin.com/Q9euzvG7

Comment: Please read a bit about how to ask, posting images or references to external sites is _not_ accepted here. Also that code does _not_ tell me what values that array contains. Please stop arguing and provide the required information _inside the question_ itself. There is an `edit` button below your question. _Use it._

Comment: @arkascha Sorry about that i don't want to argue or something like that. Here is updated version if u want anything more just tell me.

Comment: You fill the shopping cart with values received from the client side? Em..... sounds like a cheap shopping option for everyone...

Comment: @arkascha I'm assuming this is not the best way of approach...

Comment: Well, you can never trust values you receive from the client side. Anyone with a minimum of technical knowledge can manipulate those values, whether they are visible or "hidden" does not change anything. So all you should accept from the client side is a reference to a product and the quantity. All other data should be read only on the client side and has to be fetched again from the database based on the product reference (id).

Comment: @arkascha I'll chack everything tommorow and give you information how it went. Thank you so much and sorry for being unpleasant.

Comment: All fine, hope I could be of help. Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is pretty vague, I could imagine that the following could point you into the right direction:

```
<?php

$_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = [
    [
        'item_id'           =>  "id_samochodu1",
        'item_name'         =>  "hidden_name1",
        'item_brand'        =>  "hidden_brand1",
        'item_price'        =>  "hidden_price1",
        'item_quantity'     =>  "quantity1"
    ],
    [
        'item_id'           =>  "id_samochodu2",
        'item_name'         =>  "hidden_name2",
        'item_brand'        =>  "hidden_brand2",
        'item_price'        =>  "hidden_price2",
        'item_quantity'     =>  "quantity2"
    ]
]; 

$dictionary = [
    'item_id' => "id",
    'item_name' => "name", 
    'item_brand' => "brand", 
    'item_price' => "price",
    'item_quantity' => "quantity" 
];

echo '<table id="shopping-cart-content>'."\n";
foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $entry) {
    echo '<tr class="item">'."\n";
    foreach($entry as $key => $val) {
        echo sprintf(
            '<td class="prompt">%s</td><td class="value">%s</td>', 
            htmlentities($dictionary[$key]), 
            htmlentities($val))."\n";
    }
    echo '</tr>'."\n";
}
echo '</table>'."\n";
```

---

This would be another approach to data visualization based on the same input data but without the need of the dictionary:

```
echo '<table id="shopping-cart-content>'."\n";
foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $entry) {
    echo '<tr class="item">'."\n";
    echo sprintf('<td class="prompt">id</td><td>%s</td>', htmlentities($entry['item_id']))."\n";
    echo sprintf('<td class="prompt">name</td><td>%s</td>', htmlentities($entry['item_name']))."\n";
    echo sprintf('<td class="prompt">brand</td><td>%s</td>', htmlentities($entry['item_brand']))."\n";
    echo sprintf('<td class="prompt">price</td><td>%s</td>', htmlentities($entry['item_price']))."\n";
    echo sprintf('<td class="prompt">quantity</td><td>%s</td>', htmlentities($entry['item_quantity']))."\n";
    echo '</tr>'."\n";
}
echo '</table>'."\n";
```

---

The output of these two approaches is identical:

```
<table id="shopping-cart-content>
<tr class="item">
<td class="prompt">id</td><td class="value">id_samochodu1</td>
<td class="prompt">name</td><td class="value">hidden_name1</td>
<td class="prompt">brand</td><td class="value">hidden_brand1</td>
<td class="prompt">price</td><td class="value">hidden_price1</td>
<td class="prompt">quantity</td><td class="value">quantity1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
<td class="prompt">id</td><td class="value">id_samochodu2</td>
<td class="prompt">name</td><td class="value">hidden_name2</td>
<td class="prompt">brand</td><td class="value">hidden_brand2</td>
<td class="prompt">price</td><td class="value">hidden_price2</td>
<td class="prompt">quantity</td><td class="value">quantity2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! :D Thank u  so much you saved my project.